# SQL server taking too much time in opening properties in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssms, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using sql server express 2008 r2 SP2 from about 2 years. Now a days when i try to check properties of database using sql server management studio it takes too much time(25 to 30 seconds) to open properties window for any database. But other working such as connection to the server, backup of database are almost same as before.I have not changed any settings or added new large databases recently. So what may be the reason behind this slow behavior? If anyone wants extra information on this problem please let me know.

Comment: have you tried running a trace to see what exactly is taking long? (Filter the trace on you personal login.)

Comment: Agreed with @SebastianMeine.  SSMS is just like any other application, sometimes you need to look at what's happening and taking so long.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when using SSMS locally on the server or only from your desktop?

Comment: @Paul Yes. from local PC and network PC behavior is same.

Comment: @SebastianMeine How to run a trace?

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm not stating that this is **the** solution, but I have encountered various issues with various versions of SQL Server Management Studio if SSMS cannot retrieve Microsoft's Certificate Revocation List from the internet. When SSMS starts or runs various commands, it can display slow performance.

### Solution

Downloading the **MicrosoftRootAuthority.crl** file from the following location and installing it into your **trusted certificates**, can alleviate some of the issues surrounding SSMS and slow performance.

https://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/MicrosoftRootAuthority.crl